# How to apply Boolean filters with mode on Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filter

i have a Data frame like this:

```
    userId  eventType
       1    action
       1    action
       1    inactive
       1    action
       1    inactive
       1    action
       1    action
       1    action
       2    action
       2    inactive
       2    inactive
       2    action
       ....  ....
```

My goal is to filter the UserID from the user, who has the most "action" entries but at least one inactive entry as well! Pseudocode:

```
find user: max useractions & atleast one time inactive
```

Is there a smart way to do so with dataframes ...the dataframe above contains more than 10000 entrys. I could do it in a loop and iterate over each user, finde his eventTypes in a temp variable, evaluate this variable and then always update the user who meets the goal above best.

But is there a better way? I would really appreciate your help! its hard for me to get information with conditions from my data frame!
Many thanks in advance and best regards, John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a mask to filter `userId`s with at least one `'inactive'`, then filter your dataframe for those `userId`s while counting `'active'` values:

```
mask = df['eventType'] == 'inactive'
inactives = df.loc[mask, 'userId'].unique()

res = df.loc[df['userId'].isin(inactives) & ~mask, 'userId'].value_counts().index[0]  # 1
```

Note `pd.Series.value_counts` returns a series sorted by highest count first, with `userId` as index. So you can simply take the first value of its `index`.

Comment: i like the `~mask` concept in .loc. +1 :)